# How does computer interpret/understand or recognize a particular letter even if its written in different typefaces?

Tags: browser, fonts, typeface, word-processor

I expect the answer to be with respect to word processor or web browser. I am aware that ms-word has digital files, but am not able to connect the dots on how does a computer understands the glyphicon is a particular letter.

Comment: The computer stores *two* pieces of information: the unicode value of the letter and the typeface being used to display it.  You can change the typeface without changing the unicode value; a `T` is still a `T` regardless of which typeface you use.

Comment: In case i want to create my own typeface what is the basic idea in making computer understand it? How do I tell computer my glyph is also T

Comment: https://www.online-tech-tips.com/computer-tips/how-to-create-your-own-fonts-and-edit-truetype-fonts/